# How to create a function that omits key/value pairs from an object, and creates a new object with the remaining properties and values?

Tags: javascript, function, key-value, object-literal, new-object

I've been working on creating an omit function with a source and keys parameter, that checks for keys within the source, and if they are found, those properties are omitted from the source, then create a new object literal with the remaining key/value pairs within the source. So far, I've been unsuccessful, and only have been able to create a function that does the opposite of creating an object with the keys found within the source. Can anyone help figure out what I'm missing? It would be very appreciated!

```
function omit(source, keys) {
  var includedSource = {};
  for (var key in source) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (keys[i] !== key) {
        includedSource[key] = source[key];
        console.log('source[keys[i]]:', source[keys[i]]);
        console.log('includedSource:', includedSource);
      }
    }
  }
  return includedSource;
}

  function omit(source, keys) {
    var includedSource = {};
    for (var key in source) {
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (keys[i] === key) {
          includedSource[key] = source[key];
          console.log('source[keys[i]]:', source[keys[i]]);
          console.log('includedSource:', includedSource);
          }
        }
     }
     return includedSource;
   }
```

Comment: Your function doesn't check if it's found, it just checks whether it's not equivalent to *any* of the keys. Which means that as soon as you pass in two different `keys`, it will copy all keys from the `source`.

Comment: Bergi, I see what you're saying. That's where I was having issues with, figuring out how to check if any properties of source is located within keys, then returning the result into a new object. Everyone's input was very helpful! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that, `keys[i + 1]` could be equal to `key`, even though `keys[i]` does not.

To correct your code, apply following change.

```
function omit(source, keys) {
  var includedSource = {};
  for (var key in source) {
    if(!keys.includes(key)) { // <--- Change this
       includedSource[key] = source[key];
       console.log('source[keys[i]]:', source[keys[i]]);
       console.log('includedSource:', includedSource);
    }
  }
  return includedSource;
}
```

Another approach, just for fun.

```
function omit(source, keys) {
    return Object.keys(source).reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return {...acc, ...(keys.includes(curr) ? {} : {[curr]: source[curr]})}
    }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple implementation with flat object. Im not sure how would keys be declared if your object might be nested, and you would expect to extract some of N level of nested value/keys

```
const obj = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
  C: 3,
  D: 4
};

function omit(data, keys) {
  let result = {};

  for (let key in data) {
    if (keys.includes(key)) continue;

    result[key] = data[key];
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(omit(obj, ["A", "D"])) // {B: 2, C: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure and rest for a new object.

```js
function omit(object, keys) {
    let _; // prevent to be global
    for (const key of keys) ({ [key]: _, ...object } = object);
    return object;
}

console.log(omit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, ['b', 'c']));
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is use `Object.entries()` and filter the entries out that have the unwanted keys then use `Object.fromEntries()` to create the new object from the filtered entries

```js
const omit = (data, keys) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).filter(([k]) => !keys.includes(k))
  )
}


console.log(omit({ a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}, ['a', 'b']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting to entries with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and then filtering said entries with [`<Array>.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) might work nicely:

```js
const omit = (obj, keys) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(a=>!keys.includes(a[0])));
```